# Create Mosaic on image

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, quartz-core, mosaic

In image app i have to blur the selected areas of image. Something like create mosaic at selected area of image. i have to get each pixel color of selected area and then increase the size of each pixel. here is the reference link that i am using http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/05/create-mosaic-with-your-image-part-1.html . But not able to implement this practically for selected area. Can any one have some sample for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions for this

**1. Get the screen shot of the area where you want the mosaic effect and apply effect to the same portion. Then add the image(with mosaic effect) to the original image.**

**2.Get the pixel of the area you want to be effected and then gave effect to those pixels.*****